# undefined reference to TLS_server_method

Tags: c, linux, security, ssl, openssl

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.1q. When I use `TLS_server_method` in my `C` application to establish TLS handshake on tlsv1.3, I get error, `undefined reference to TLS_server_method`.

Online articles suggesting that, this is what has to be used when establishing SSL context for tlsv1.3 like

```
ssl_server_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());
```

I do not find the body of the function or macro -> TLS_server_method inside OpenSSL source. I can find the bodies of functions `tlsv1_2_server_method`, `DTLSv1_2_server_method`, etc. in **ssl/methods.c** and the same work for me from my application with same linker options, but not `TLS_server_method`.

Is TLS_server_method auto-generated via some configuration prior to building OpenSSL? Can someone throw light on it?

Comment: If you're looking at the openssl source code then you need to build it first. And even then it can be difficult to find things because openssl uses complicated macros in their source code. Instead, provide a [mre] in your question and describe how you are compiling and linking the program.

Answer (score 1):

This C program works for me:

```
/* ot.c */
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  SSL_CTX *ssl_server_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  return ctx ? 0 : 2;
}
```

This is how I compile and run it (without the leading `$`):

```
$ gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Wextra -o ot ot.c -lssl && ./ot && echo OK
OK
```

If you get the *undefined reference to TLS_server_method* error, then you most likely forgot to specify `-lssl` in the `gcc` command. For example:

```
$ gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Wextra -o ot ot.c
/tmp/cc8tP5JH.o: In function `main':
ot.c:(.text.startup+0x5): undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
ot.c:(.text.startup+0xd): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These functions are available in my system's OpenSSL (not necessarily 1.1.1q):

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so | grep _server_method
000000000001fe80 T DTLS_server_method
000000000001ff70 T DTLSv1_2_server_method
000000000001ffa0 T DTLSv1_server_method
000000000001fd90 T TLS_server_method
000000000001ff10 T TLSv1_1_server_method
000000000001fee0 T TLSv1_2_server_method
000000000001ff40 T TLSv1_server_method
```

> I do not find the body of the function or macro -> TLS_server_method inside OpenSSL source

I've downloaded https://ftp.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz from the official location and I've extracted it, then I've searched for `TLS_server_method`. In the file `ssl/methods.c` I've found:

```
IMPLEMENT_tls_meth_func(TLS_ANY_VERSION, 0, 0, 
                        TLS_server_method,
                        ossl_statem_accept,
                        ssl_undefined_function, TLSv1_2_enc_data)
```

In the file `ssl/ssl_local.h`, I've found

```
# define IMPLEMENT_tls_meth_func(version, flags, mask, func_name, s_accept, \
                                 s_connect, enc_data) \
const SSL_METHOD *func_name(void)  \
```

Together this means that the function `TLS_server_method` is defined in `ssl/methods.c` using the macro `IMPLEMENT_tls_meth_func` defined in `ssl/ssl_local.h`.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how TLS_server_method is defined. But it is not true that I have not linked my program with libssl. It is there in the makefile. All other functions like tlsv1_2_server_method() work fine. Anyway I have been using TLSv1.2 for the same program with same linker options which invokes the needed libssl functions.

Comment: I've added an `nm -D` command to my answer with which you can check which functions are available.

Comment: Are you sure you are using OpenSSL 1.1.1q and not something older (like 1.1.0b or earlier)? The `CHANGES` file in OpenSSL 1.1.1q mentions the introduction of `TLS_server_method` in 1.1.0c.

Comment: yes I am using OpenSSL 1.1.1q. I will check nm output.

Comment: Thank you. Root cause - this is an embedded target with seperate partitions for 2 different CPUs. Both of them have this TLS application and only 1 of them uses it. The one which is not used is also compiled from a top level makefile along with the one which is used, on the host build machine, and the one which is not used links with older libssl.1.0.0. Since SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method()) was called from both the applications as it is in a common utility C file , the undefined reference was thrown from the linking of app which is not used. It works fine when the used app is built seperately